# Nativescript with Firebase : Works login in offline mode

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I use nativescript-plugin-firebase to connect with Firebase. It does work when create new user / login / CRUD operations when app is online mode.

When the app is offline mode, Login authentication / Create new user is not working rest of the above mentioned things are working.

My code base:
app.component.ts

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
        firebase.init({
          persist: true,
          storageBucket: 'gs://**************/',
          onAuthStateChanged: (data: any) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            if (data.loggedIn) {
              BackendService.token = data.user.uid;
            }
            else {
              BackendService.token = "";
            }
          }
        }).then(
          function (instance) {
            console.log("firebase.init done");
          },
          function (error) {
            console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
          }
          );
firebase.keepInSync(
        "/users", // which path in your Firebase needs to be kept in sync?
        true      // set to false to disable this feature again
    ).then(
        function () {
            console.log("firebase.keepInSync is ON for /users");
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("firebase.keepInSync error: " + error);
        }
    );
```

in service file

```
login(user: User) {
return firebase.login({
  type: firebase.LoginType.PASSWORD,
  email: user.email,
  password: user.password
}).then((result: any) => {
      BackendService.token = result.uid;
      return JSON.stringify(result);
  }, (errorMessage: any) => {
    // alert(errorMessage);
    alert('Email address / Password is wrong!!!');
  });
```

}

Anyone help me how login will work in when offline mode.

Comment: Any updates on the question? Will authentication service work in offline ?